# What are the best LEGO storage options?

Tags: storage

I have several Lego sets and I usually build them and then make them small enough so they fit back in the box for long term storage . . . but my dream is that I can take apart my model and organize the parts and just keep the books so I can put them back together again later.

(I read you can get the books as PDF's from the official site now . . . I need to try that out.)

I figure I could use some sort of plastic organizers from IKEA or something. What methods have you used? Do you store them by size and color or just dump them all into bins and let the creativity happen?

Comment: I remember a funny article on this which shows how someone sorted their LEGOs as their collection grew over the decades... I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: What, a closet with no temperature-control whatsoever?

Comment: @muntoo [this lugnet article](http://news.lugnet.com/storage/?n=707) may be what you are looking for. I just read it again, it's really worth it.

Comment: @Joubarc Yes, that was it!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I prefer what I call the "block" method. You can get to almost every piece in less than 3 steps.

[image]

I was inspired by this: http://www.evilmadscientist.com/article.php/efficientlego

Comment: I guess you could have a few 'blocks', but if you want a large number of one type of piece, it will be best to have most of your LEGO sorted by piece type. When you need more 'blocks', just build them. (Maybe have a LEGO Mindstorms Robot help you sort...? ;))

Comment: Lots of great options here but this is the one that really made me think. I stacked the small parts like this AND THEN put them in a storage bin as described in other questions.

Comment: I love this idea, specially because it can be mixed and matched with regular "bag of legos", organizing just the ones that are smaller and harder to find. Also, I found the Flickr set for all of the original author images: https://www.flickr.com/photos/oskay/albums/72157603604216252

Answer (score 23):

I'm a big fan of Simon Sheehan's answer, and use a bunch of those myself for a lot of those small "technic" LEGO pieces.

But once your collection grows too big, it's time to dedicate a wall to your collection:

[image: Lego Bins]

I find these at [Global Industrial Supply](http://www.globalindustrial.com/g/storage/bins-totes-containers/tip-out-bins/plastic-stackable-tip-out-bins):

[image: Global Supply]

These clear tilt-out storage bins are stackable and sturdy and just about perfect to catalog your pieces by shape.  Easy to find (for the most part) because you see the pieces.  Sorting by color is not worth the effort-- too many colors.

The one thing they are NOT good for are large base plates.

Some of the standard 4-2 bricks, 4-1 bricks, 2-2 bricks are too plentiful, in which case I just have a simple plastic pullout drawer for those.

Something like this from the Container Store:

[image: Containers]

Comment: I've recently purchased quite a few of these tip-out bins from Global, and they are VERY nice. I feel they are worth the extra money - great for small bits and specialized pieces. They are easily stackable and have holes on the back for mounting.

Answer (score 20):

I took all my blocks out and layed them out on a table. This took a few days actually. From there I purchased a plastic storage container from an IKEA type location, that had multiple bins that slid in. It looked a lot like this:

[image: bins]

They are intended for crafts, but Lego is a craft too! From there I sorted it like so:

1. 2x2 bricks
2. 4x4 bricks
3. Flat pieces
4. Large items (Trains, road pieces, etc.)
5. Bricks larger than 5x5
6. Bricks larger than 10x10.
7. Specialty parts (Airplane wings, etc)

It really bottles down to what YOU want. Take an inventory of what pieces you have - whatever you have a large number of, fill a container with an appropriately sized bin for that many pieces.

Comment: My only issue with the drawers is that I've knocked those over and had to resort the contents before! Could be a good option if I connect it to a table or something!

Comment: @tooshel Perhaps you could get ones that do not actually come completely out.

Comment: I hate these things with a vengeance. You're constantly opening and closing drawers since the thing becomes unstable with more than one open at a time. Good for screws, not for Lego bricks.

Answer (score 16):

I've used those stack-able organizer cases for years.  They are great for storage and access to the parts is a lot easier than in drawers.  Another big advantage over the drawer-organizers is how easy they are to transport.

[image]

You might have noticed that they are now empty.  That's because my kids are now 7 and I've decided to mix my Lego blocks with theirs (they get a lot more usage now).  Of course young kids and neat organization doesn't mix very well so I've reverted to the good old bins on the floor.  I prefer the big clear plastic ones with rollers underneath.  We can roll them under the futon when it's not in use.

[image]

I love the sound of bricks when we're all digging around.

Comment: When using big bins, use big, low ones. Good advise, and that one one of the less efficient methoed!

Comment: That yellow organizer case you have on the right in the top picture, that seems to be a nice thing. It appears that you can re-organize the sections in it. Do you mind posting the URL of that or something similar? Thanks.

Comment: I got this at a renovation centre.  Google this: Stanley 17-Compartment Small Parts Storage Organizer

Answer (score 10):

These bins would work well.  Others have mentioned children and these would work well especially for kids. (This one can be found on Amazon [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HY3PXI).)

[image]

Adults could use this kind also or go for an industrial looking version like this:

[image]

(This one can be found [here](http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/597939795/Wall_mounted_plastic_storage_bin.html).)

Comment: Those wall-mounted plastic bins in the second example are actually used in professional [LEGO model workshops](http://www.flickr.com/photos/rabidnovaracer/3733471573/in/faves-ambo100/). They're hard wearing and very easy to use but they can also be very pricey!

Answer (score 5):

An old bed-sheet can be used to create a sack that both stores the Lego bricks and doubles as a play mat. As a child, this is how my parents stored our Lego and it meant we never had a difficult task when it came time to pack it away.

The only downsides are that some bricks can be hard to find against the sheet (depending on colour) and there's zero organisation.

Answer (score 5):

An honourable mention should go to the forthcoming IKEA / LEGO joint storage solution - BYGGLEK

These will arrive in store in October 2020, and consist of plastic boxes in various sizes, with a studded top, and 'label' in front.

[Details on the IKEA US website](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/new/get-ready-for-bygglek-collection-in-october-pubd4911960)

[More details on the IKEA Deutschland page](https://www.ikea.com/de/de/new/bygglek-ikea-lego-kollektion-aufbewahrungsboxen-pubc6912e50)

Answer (score 2):

I sort my bricks by type. Common bricks, plates like 2x3, 2x4 or 2x2x4,2x2x6 go in big IKEA boxes (800.892.39) and all other parts go in boxes with dividers (Lunar Box, not sure about the manufacturer). Body parts and accessories are stored in big IKEA boxes too.

Answer (score 2):

My approach on the cheap side. I use small transparent containers left from food for small items and  transparent plastic bags. If container is full than this type goes to a bag. Put them all to big IKEA type containers. [image]

Sorted by type mostly (not color), about 20 types:

1) 1xX bricks 6 units high (normal)

2) 1xX bricks 2 units high (low)

3) 2xX bricks 6 units high (normal)

4) 2xX bricks 2 units high (low)

5) plates square all sizes

6) pins technic

7) axles

8) rounded bricks

9) wheels and related

10) rear and related

11) bricks with prints and pictures

12) windows, doors, etc.

13) minifigures

14) decorations

15 +) ... etc.