# Does the LEGO company sell LEGO brick organization bins?

Tags: storage, organisation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some storage options?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/122/what-are-some-storage-options)

Are there official LEGO brick storage and organization bins available?  If not, then what good 3rd party options are there?  I'm looking to transition away from just having large plastic boxes filled with LEGO bricks that require me digging through, and going to having a way to quickly access specific bricks I need when building.

Comment: These are the best containers I've used: http://www.harborfreight.com/24-divider-storage-container-94458.html -- Pull-out bins tend to be a hassle when you want an individual piece as you have to search for it.

Comment: @Pubby8 Please add that as an answer.

Comment: [Similar question?](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/122/what-are-some-storage-options)

Comment: @daviesgeek Yeah, I'd close my question as a dupe of that one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The LEGO company has indeed regularly issued [storage](http://www.brickset.com/search/?query=storage) solutions. They may be great for kids (the latest ones are brick-shaped), but let's face it, for serious fans they are mostly pointless. And expensive.

Depending on the size of your collection and your sorting method (which is another debate, but remember to sort by form first, not by color), you'll want to switch to do-it-yourself storage racks (the ones with lots of plastic drawers) or whatever you fancy. If using drawers, make sure they are translucid, or have a sticker with the image of the part on them. (LEGOland designers glue one specimen of the actual part).

Some people just buy translucid boxes, try to find some shop which sells them in bulk (like, by 100 pieces), ask a caterer where he finds his for example.

It will require some experimenting anyway, so don't buy too much of an expensive item before being sure it's right for you.

Comment: Any suggestions for retailers in the UK?

Comment: AKRO seems to have the [kind of containers](http://www.akro.co.uk/plastic_takeaway_containers-(9766).php) I had in mind, but that's just from 5 minutes googling, I don't live in the UK.

Comment: These clear plastic AKRO containers are commonly used in UK takeaways (takeout?)! I'd never thought of using them for this before now.