# How to store large amounts of bigger bricks?

Tags: storage

I am aware of [this](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/122/what-are-some-storage-options) question and of [this](http://www.evilmadscientist.com/2008/how-to-organize-your-lego-bricks-for-efficient-building/) post blog on Evil Mad Scientist which include a couple of interesting. My issue with the first one is that it is completely unsuitable for larger amounts of bigger bricks (like 2x2, 1x4, 2x4 and so on) and I'd like to avoid stacking presented in the second link.

I thought long and the best idea I had is to get a couple of the [Lego Storage bricks](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Lego-Storage-Brick-8-Red/dp/B003NE5L6S/) in different colors and store particular color in particular box. The problem is, if I had 50 yellow 2x2, 50 yellow 2x3 and 50 yellow 2x4, I'd have hard time finding two 2x8. Not to mention different shapes and sizes of plates, technic bricks with holes and the studless technics.

Perhaps I am asking for impossible, but **are there any solutions for storing large amount of bricks, technic bricks, technic studless bricks and plates in different shapes and colors (I am thinking at least 10 per color & shape and 5 per color & shape of the less popular combinations for the starts) in a way which makes it easy to find the exact piece you want?** I don't mind mixing different shapes or colors as long as the big volume of one type won't make it too difficult to find others in the same container.

Comment: The link you give is to arranging your build area, but you ask about storage. The two are not always the same - many of us store a lot of Lego and have a "build area collection" that's smaller.

Comment: @Ӎσᶎ I didn't realize that people keep separate stashes for immediate building and for long-term storage. It's a good thing to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a great deal on your play style and just how much Lego you have, and on what other skills and equipment you have. Using official Lego containers is the most expensive and least flexible option, as they are not really in the storage business. The [Technic Briefcase](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=8062-1) is a good start if you have Technic, but those get pricey if you want more than a couple.
[image: Technic Briefcase]

The basic idea is there though - you want a lot of compartments in a few different sizes. Many people buy plastic storage systems, either tackle boxes or drawers (or both), in quantities ranging from "a couple" to "the entire wall of my playroom". Drawers have the advantage that they stack vertically very well, so you can fit a lot of compartments in a small-ish space, and you can get systems that lock together or attach to the wall. Tackle boxes are more portable but harder to get things out of, and organising the boxes can get ugly when you get a lot of them. But I prefer tackle boxes because they give me a wider variety of parts per area of desk, and they're portable.

Since I'm kinda crafty in other ways, I actually built my own tackle box like trays out of wood. That has the advantage that I can customise them exactly how I want them, but obviously I needed a table saw and other tools to build them. [Photos here](http://moz.net.nz/lego/2011-12-misc/)

[image: Lego play area] ([bigger photo](http://moz.net.nz/lego/2011-12-misc/desk-and-shelves-2.jpg))

Comment: Awesome photo! So, basically, it boils down to two options: a lot of organiser boxes, and the remaining excess stashed assembled like in Evil Mad Scientist blog post (or not) in a remoter place?

Comment: Or you can have a build area and big boxes. Ok, another option: big boxes, optionally with zip-lock bags containing sorted parts. I don't know anyone who actually does big boxes full of loose parts, but it's possible. The box+bag option is very compact, where drawers or organiser boxes end up with a lot of wasted space. I do the box+bag approach, except that I have a box of (Technic) wheels. Plus the shelves you see in the photo. Technic tends to be pretty high volume - lots of big parts.

Comment: I have quite different experience with technic size, but then again my collection is still pretty small. Technic takes about half of the pieces I have and less than third of the space used.

Comment: Yeah, admittedly I have rather lots of Technic... http://www.moz.net.nz/lego/roadtrain2/